# hapi 17 with joi validation AssertionError

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I'm porting an existing Hapi 16 app to Hapi 17 - and have run into problems with Joi validation...

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    'use strict';

const Joi = require('joi');

const validator = Joi.object({
        "sku": Joi.string().required(),
        "name": Joi.string()
      // cut for berevity..
        )
  })

module.exports = {
  method: ["POST", "PUT"],
  path: "/api/products",
  options: {
    validate: {
      params: validator
    },
    async handler(request, h) {
      try {
        const updateOrCreateItemQuery = { sku: request.payload.sku };        
        const result = await request.postItem( "product", updateOrCreateItemQuery);
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
        throw h.internal("Internal MongoDB error", err);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

When I start the app (not when I visit the route) I get the following error:  `{ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot set path parameters validations without path parameters: POST /api/products`

I've stripped everything back - so its just this route. Its deffinately something to do with Joi, as when I remove the validation - it works... I've read the docs - and cant see what I'm doing wrong...

( I have applied various decorators to the request object - eg postItem etc, which... posts an item to the DB)

Comment: Been told by a pal I don't need Joi object - that i should pass the validation schema as just a plain old object. I'm on the train at the mo... will test when home :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    'use strict';

const Joi = require('joi');

const validator = {
        "sku": Joi.string().required(),
        "name": Joi.string()
      // cut for berevity..
        )
  }

module.exports = {
  method: ["POST", "PUT"],
  path: "/api/products",
  options: {
    validate: {
      payload: validator
    },
    async handler(request, h) {
      try {
        const updateOrCreateItemQuery = { sku: request.payload.sku };        
        const result = await request.postItem( "product", updateOrCreateItemQuery);
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
        throw h.internal("Internal MongoDB error", err);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Turned validate into a regular object, and set the validate option to payload.... which makes sense, as this is a this route accepts POST and PUT.